# sorting a vector of structs using <algorithm>

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, struct

I know there are already questions about it, and i followed all the tips, but it still doesn't work, so I'll be happy ti understand what's wrong.

I have this struct:

```
struct Scores
{
    int _score;
    std::string _name;
};
```

and I want to sort the vector by the _score - from high to low. this is what I wrote:

```
std::sort (_scores.begin(), _scores.end(), myFunction);
```

I have this function:

```
bool myFunction (const struct Scores &i, const struct Scores &j)
    {return i._score>j._score;}
```

I've included algorithm, so I really don't know what is the problem. I get these errors:

```
error C3867: 'HighScores::myFunction': function call missing argument list;
error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

Thank you

Comment: is myFunction a member function? Then it should be static.

Comment: `myFunction` needs to be `static` if it is a member function.

Comment: This error is nonsense >> *'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : **expects 2 arguments - 3 provided***.

Comment: To add up on Alan's comment, calling a member function is conceptually different than calling a non-member function.
HighScores::myFunction(i,j) is in fact called like HighScores::myFunction(<pointer to object>, i,j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like myFunction in your example is member class function. It has to be static then to be a right predicate to the `std::sort` algorithm. Alternatively you can make this function a free outstanding function.

Or you can make a functor

```
struct Sorter {
  bool operator ()( const Scores &o1, const Scores &o2) {
      return o1._score > o2._score;
  }
};
```

and pass an instance of this to the algorithm:

```
std::sort ( _scores.begin(), _scores.end(), Sorter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @bits_international answer you can also do it like that in C++11

```
std::sort(_scores.begin(), _scores.end(), [](const Score& a, const Score& b) {
    return a._score > b._score;
});
```

I hope it helped.